# App.xaml resource not reachable in main window

Tags: wpf, resources

I'm receiving an exception in main window's constructor:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Operacja podawania wartości elementu „System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder” wywołała wyjątek., numer wiersza 229, pozycja 18.'

Nie można znaleźć zasobu o nazwie „PopupBorderBackgroundColor”. W nazwach zasobów jest uwzględniana wielkość liter.
```

It says: "Cannot find resource with name „PopupBorderBackgroundColor” ".

Exception is thrown in line with `InitializeComponent()`. Note, that this resource actually *is* in available from application resources.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    if (Application.Current.Resources["PopupBorderBackgroundColor"] == null)
        throw new Exception();

    InitializeComponent();

    viewModel = Dependencies.Container.Instance.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("access", this));
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Application ctor looks like this:

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    (...)

    var configService = Container.Instance.Resolve<IConfigurationService>();
    configService.ProcessConfiguration(config =>
    {
        var styleResources = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TfsNotifier;Component\\Theme\\Styles.xaml") };

        if (config.Theme == Theme.Light)
        {
            //
            // v HERE is the resource
            //
            styleResources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TfsNotifier;Component\\Theme\\ColorsLight.xaml") });
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml") });
        }
        else
        {
            styleResources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TfsNotifier;Component\\Theme\\ColorsDark.xaml") });
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Dark.Blue.xaml") });
        }

        styleResources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TfsNotifier;Component\\Theme\\Fonts.xaml") });
        styleResources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TfsNotifier;Component\\Theme\\Dimensions.xaml") });

        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(styleResources);
    });

    //
    // Another check passed
    //

    if (!(Resources["PopupBorderBackgroundColor"] is System.Windows.Media.Color))
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Why cannot I reach resource in application from its main window?

Comment: It's just my guess, but how about doing the same in `OnStartup` method?

Comment: I think you should be picking your resources and merging them before the mainwindow tries to use them. If necessary ensuring the mainwindow has no dependencies in it's ctor. Make it load content. I'd also consider writing a resource dictionary to disk as a flat file that loads all the dicfinaries etc that the user has chosen as preferences.